# Replace empty string with space

Tags: python

Hello I started learning Python and I've come across a problem. 
 I want to replace each empty string in a list with a space (" "). 
For example, if I call the function with `function(['', 'x', 'x', '', '', 'y', 'y', '', 'a'])` I would like to return a string `' xx  yy a'`.

```py
def function(a):
    for i in a:
        if i == None:
            a[i] = " "
    string = "".join(a)
    return string
```

Comment: Well, an empty string does *not* equal `None`. An empty string equals an empty string: `if i == ''`…

Comment: also consider removing trailing whitespaces

Comment: When you're posting Python code, make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately. Badly indented Python code is nonsense. Also, you need `def` to define a function.

Answer (score 5):

Use a generator expression instead with a short-circuiting `or`:

```
def function(a):
    return ''.join(char or ' ' for char in a)
```

If the character is a non-empty string, it'll be used as is. Otherwise, a space will be used.

Comment: I love this solution. Short and sweet, based on the fact that an empty string is evaluated to `False`.

Comment: def function(a):
    return ''.join(char or ' ' for char in a)

my_list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '']
print(function(my_list))

output: hello world

Answer (score 1):

to  replace None , False and  empty  strings

```
>>> a = ['','11',None,'22',False]

>>> b=[elem if elem else " " for elem in a]

>>> ''.join(b)
   ' 11 22 '
>>>
```

note that   your code would not  replace '' as '' is not  None

```
>>>''==None

False

>>>
```

Comment: @khelwood - Generally not, but comprehensions have their own scope, so it's not too terrible. But it's not entirely okay, either. :P

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 In Python 3 they have their own scope. In Python 2, they don't.

Comment: @khelwood - Well, Python 2 is silly like that sometimes.

Comment: I agree and renamed  the var.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def function(a):
    return ''.join(char or ' ' for char in a)

my_list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '']
print(function(my_list))
```

**output:** hello world

This function is work properly. When you want empty string of array list element replace with whitespace. I submit the answer after testing the code.